Soft Question - Book Techniques with notes
Do you guys have any concrete techniques for consuming and extracting material and concepts from math texts quickly? My library is growing and I have a set trajectory of the texts I will read, but the books are many.
The good thing is, math texts are often uniform in their structure, there are concrete units of content: definitions, theorems and lemmas with proofs, examples, and sometimes discussions. Which leads me to believe there must be some nice system for reading and note taking to go through the texts efficiently. The issue that I run into with just noting definitions and theorems and reading the proofs leads to a weak understanding of the motivation and intuition. Both of which are very valuable to my mathematical journey and perhaps why I take so much time with a text.
This specifically goes out to any academics who are skilled in shoveling through papers. What are your techniques?
